Unable to find VUE folder in starport project
I am new to blockchain and recently started using starport to set up my first project. As a part of starport their is supposed to be a a folder vue for running a interface for interacting with the chain, However I am unable to find this folder in my directory, how do I obtain this?
I tried to check the version of starport and it is up to date.

which github repo did you clone?
